# I got no formal invitation. Is it normal?

Tags: support

This morning I found out on Area51 that the site just entered private beta. I was committed, so I thought I would have received the link to participate: but I got no such link. Is it normal?

(of course, since I am writing here, it means that I **can** access the site, so there is no real problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Private beta invitations were sent out to all committers. The most common reason for missing notices is either failing to verify your email address when setting up your Area 51 account, the email being sent to your 'spam' folder, or the occasional "oops, I didn't see it" response.

Glad to see you made it, regardless. Welcome to the site!

Comment: ok, your first reason was the right one. When Italian.SE started, I received the invitation at an old email address of mine, and so I noticed it only after a couple of days. So I decided to change my email address to the one I use to log in SE... and I did not think that I had to confirm it anyway.